# parallel payments using gateways

Tags: payment-gateway

In my web application, users should be able to purchase service from different service providers. Payment gateway will handle the payment so that money from user will be transferred to providers account.

Now there is a requirement, when a payment is done, I need to split in to two portions, like 95%, and 5%, and the 5% should be deposited in our Account(As a service charge).

Can we make parallel payments like this with any gateways working in India?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a payment gateway in India, my experience is, that it is not possible. Ofcourse technically it should be possible, but the main payment gateways in India do not have this option. First reason would be a legal issue, who is liable when receiving the funds, the service provider or you. A payment gateway will not even try.

An option would be that the amount is transferred to your account and from there you sent 95% to the other service providers.